# Why opacity and rotate not work with @page?

Tags: html, css, pdf, rotation, opacity

I am creating a watermark in html page like this

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
     @page {
      margin: 3cm 1cm 3cm 1cm;
      size: A4 portrait;
      @left-middle{
        content: element(watermarked)
      }
     }

     div.watermarked {
      position: running(watermarked);
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 200px;
      color: #000000;
      z-index: -99;
      top: 50%;
      left: 25%;
      opacity: 0.1;
      -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
      transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="watermarked">Preview</div>
</body>
```

But it seem like the opacity and the transform rotate not work.
Is there any way to handle this issue?
Update: I use this html to render into pdf by xhtmlrenderer library

Comment: Looks like it works fine on Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/zb4ev7j8/

Comment: Yeah, it works on chrome, but when I render it to pdf, it's not work

Comment: It may be worth providing some details about how you're using that library and tagging it so people familiar can help you with it.

Comment: `@page` only has a very limited properties that it can change. Try `@print` instead